# Unprotected embankment?

Tags: flooring, structural, construction, excavation

I am studying my first building custruction course and I got the an example house plan from the instructor and there is mention *unprotected embankment here 640.25* .I couldn't understand what is meant by unprotected embankment?

Comment: ift possibly means no retainig wall or no fence at the top, it's hard toi guess without context.

Comment: It is often better to ask your instructor as practices vary around the World and we are from different places…

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

An "embankment" is a raised earth to either separate/protect an area from the waterway, such as a levee; or divert, collect, and drain the storm water runoffs, such as the raised earth at the highway entrance/exit ramps.

The sloping surface of the raised earth (embankment) requires protection to avoid the fine soil particles been washed away by the flowing water, and corrosion and weakening of the soil due to long-term exposure to water and weather.

The usual protection materials are rip-raps or concrete facing for the levee, and grass, patterned cement tiles, or concrete facing for the highway embankment.